# storing data to mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

my code wont insert into the student table I dont know whats wrong could you guys possibly help? I tried to print and error message in each line to find out where the error was but I got no errors so I'm confused

```
<?PHP

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {



$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect :' . mysql_error());
}
$Selected= mysql_select_db("elearningg", $link);
if (!$Selected) {
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}


$sql    = "INSERT INTO  student (FirstName, LastName, UserName,Password,  confirmP ,phoneNum,Email) VALUES ('$_POST[FN]','$_POST[LN]','$_POST[userName]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[confirmPass]','$_POST[number]','$_POST[email]') ";

mysql_query($sql,$link);


mysql_close($link);

}


?>
```

and here's the html form:

```
     <form  method="post" action="Register.php">
    <div class="contact-to">

     <P> <input name="FN" type="text" class="text" value="First name"  > 

      <input name="LN" type="text" class="text" value="Last name"  style="margin-left: 10px">
      <input name="userName" type="text" class="text" value="username"  style="margin-left: 10px">
    </div>
      <div class="contact-to">

      <input name="password" type="text" class="text" value="Password"  style="margin-left: 10px">
      <input name="confirmPass" type="text" class="text" value="Confirm password" style="margin-left: 10px">
       <input name="number" type="text" class="text" value="Phone Number" >
        <input name="email" type="text" class="text" value="email" >
    </div>

    <div> <input  value="submit" type="submit" class="submit"> </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: If you're trying to validate `$_POST['submit']` after user clicks the button, you should include attribute `name` inside your submit tag like this: `<input  value="submit" type="submit"name="submit" class="submit">`

Comment: Have you tracked down the execution of the script to see where it hangs? You're also open to SQL injections with this code, don't trust user inputs.

Comment: try adding: die(mysql_error()); Also, escape your values.

Comment: Make sure you have error_reporting enabled if it isn't already. Just add error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors',1); at the top of your pages.

Comment: Storing passwords in plain text rather than a hash, *tsk, tsk*. I hope this is for educational purposes and not intended to go live.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to validate `$_POST['submit']` after user clicks the button, you should include attribute `name` inside your input submit tag like this:

```
<input value="submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">
```

And then you can check $_POST:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // your code
}
```

PHP will always return false in your condition without a attribute name...

- Also, consider using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: *"Also, consider using mysqli with prepared statements, or PDO with prepared statements, they're much safer."* - Now where have I seen that before? lol déjà vue.

Comment: Ouch. I'm a bad student, professor @Fred-ii-. I didn't ask permission to post this phrase. Here I go... May I? =D

Comment: Oh sure, if it's used for good and not for evil. Many others are using some of my other quotes too lol - thanks ;-)

Comment: @bcesars what kind of type `Bode` and POST submit you telling about? do you agree? what you think?

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql insert query code to this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

function debug($data){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
}
function getConnected($host,$user,$pass,$db) {

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    if($mysqli->connect_error)
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

    return $mysqli;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    debug('Connecting database...');

    $link = getConnected('localhost','root','', 'stackoverflow');

    debug('Database connected...');
    $sql    = "
        INSERT INTO  `student` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `UserName`, `Password`, `confirmP`, `phoneNum`, `Email`) 
        VALUES (
            '{$_POST['FN']}',
            '{$_POST['LN']}',
            '{$_POST['userName']}',
            '{$_POST['password']}',
            '{$_POST['confirmPass']}',
            '{$_POST['number']}',
            '{$_POST['email']}'
        )";

    if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        debug("Errormessage: ". mysqli_error($link)."\n");
    }else{
        debug('Query executed successfully...');
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Also change your form submit button code to this:

```
<div> <input  name="submit" value="submit" type="submit" class="submit"> </div>
```

Comment: changed it but still wont add to the database :(

Comment: I just updated the code, can you please run it and let me know the status. I added new line to print if there is any error in order to run query.

Comment: '; print_r($data); echo ''; } function getConnected($host,$user,$pass,$db) { $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db); if($mysqli->connect_error) die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error()); return $mysqli; } if(isset($_POST['submit']))

Comment: { $link = getConnected('localhost','root','', 'stackoverflow'); $sql = " INSERT INTO `student` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `UserName`, `Password`, `confirmP`, `phoneNum`, `Email`) VALUES ( '{$_POST['FN']}', '{$_POST['LN']}', '{$_POST['userName']}', '{$_POST['password']}', '{$_POST['confirmPass']}', '{$_POST['number']}', '{$_POST['email']}' )"; if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) { debug("Errormessage: ". mysqli_error($link)."\n"); } mysqli_close($link); } ?> ?>

Comment: this is what i got on the beginning of the page

Comment: @noura, kindly copy my latest script, run it, and if there is any error, do let me know, it should work